# sas reference cell values of table

Tags: sas

I'm trying to reference values that are in a stats table, as such:

```
/* Calculate Median and IQR */
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = kddcup98(drop=TARGET_B) OUTTABLE= boxStats(keep=_VAR_ _Q1_ _Q3_ _QRANGE_) NOPRINT;
RUN; 

/* Calculate upper and lower bounds */
DATA boxStats;
   SET boxStats;
   upper_bound = _Q3_ + 1.5*_QRANGE_;
   lower_bound = _Q3_ - 1.5*_QRANGE_;
RUN;


DATA kddcup98_continuous;
   SET kddcup98_continuous;
   ARRAY Num_Col[*] _NUMERIC_;
      DO i = 1 to dim(Num_Col);
         IF Num_Col[i] > boxStats[i, "upper_bound"] OR Num_Col[i] < boxStats[i, "lower_bound"] THEN Num_Col[i] = .;
      END;
RUN;
```

I have the main data table and a table of stats from which I computed upper and lower bounds. I need to reference those values from the boxStats table. How I can I reference those values?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use OUTTABLE PROC statement option.

OUTTABLE=SAS-data-set 
creates an output data set that contains univariate statistics arranged in tabular form, with one observation per analysis variable. See the section OUTTABLE= Output Data Set for details.

Comment: How do I use it after that? This is what I'm trying to do: `DATA missing_values;
SET data;
ARRAY outlier _numeric_;
 DO OVER outlier;
  IF (outlier > &p75 + 1.5 * &iqr) OR (outlier < &p25 - 1.5 * &iqr) THEN outlier = .; 
 END;
RUN;`